# UI-Router – Upgraded to 0.2.10, Nested & Named View No Longer Rendering, Why?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I just upgraded Angular UI-Router and my nested & named view no longer renders.  Did something change, what happened here?  The `ui-view="issues"` template no longer renders and the div shows up empty...

**My Router State:**

```
    // Town
    .state('town', {
        url: "/:townShortId/:townName/:page",
        views: {
            "header":    {  templateUrl: "views/header/town.html"   },
            "content":   {  templateUrl: "views/content/town.html"  },
         // Issues = the nested and named view
            "issues":    {  templateUrl: "views/issues/town.html"  },
            "footer":    {  templateUrl: "views/footer/town.html"  }
        }
     })
```

**My Container JADE file:**

```
block content
  section.content
  section.container
    div(ui-view="header")
    div(ui-view="content")
    div(ui-view="footer")
```

**The HTML being rendered in ui-view="content"**

```
<div id="lower-navigation" class="row">
        <div id="main-container" class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
            <div class="row"> 

                <div id="issues-container" class="col-md-5" ui-view="issues"></div> <!-- ui-view=issues -->

            </div> <!-- row -->
        </div> <!-- #main-container -->
</div> <!-- row -->
```